# Check for similarities in multiple lists and return match/

Tags: python, list

I have four lists with strings:

```
a = ['A', 'B', 'GG', 'Z']
b = ['A', 'F', 'GG', 'Z']
c = ['A', 'P', 'E', 'Z']
d = ['A', 'T', 'R', 'Z']
```

and I want to return a single list that has the string that appears in all lists to get:

```
final_list = ['A', 'Z']
```

I know you can use `set` and `intersection` but these use at most one argument whilst I have four. Is there another way of doing this?

Thank you.

**EDIT**

I tried:

```
final_list = set(a).intersection(b,c,d)
```

Does it matter which order the lists are placed?

Comment: `set.intersection(*map(set,[a,b,c,d]))`

Comment: I suggest a very slight modification (wrapping in `list()`) to meet the OP's return requirement.  `list(set.intersection(*map(set,[a,b,c,d])))`

Answer (score 1):

Using a list comprehension along with `zip` with an equality check:

```
[chars[0] for chars in zip(a,b,c,d) if len(set(chars)) <= 1]
```

Comment: This method is good for readability - so I checked the timings of this and the method suggested in the OP's comment using `list(set())`.  These methods ran within 0.05us of each other.

Comment: The difference between this and the one in OP's question and the comment is this takes ordering into consideration whereas the other doesn't.